# Calculating n x n determinant

Tags: c#, matrix

According to instructions and sample code from [MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj863137.aspx) and comments from post here [determinant of n x n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530143/deteminant-of-nn-matrix)...

I changed code to be like this:

```
using System;

internal class MatrixDecompositionProgram
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        float[,] m = MatrixCreate(4, 4);
        m[0, 0] = 3.0f; m[0, 1] = 7.0f; m[0, 2] = 2.0f; m[0, 3] = 5.0f;
        m[1, 0] = 1.0f; m[1, 1] = 8.0f; m[1, 2] = 4.0f; m[1, 3] = 2.0f;
        m[2, 0] = 2.0f; m[2, 1] = 1.0f; m[2, 2] = 9.0f; m[2, 3] = 3.0f;
        m[3, 0] = 5.0f; m[3, 1] = 4.0f; m[3, 2] = 7.0f; m[3, 3] = 1.0f;

        int[] perm;
        int toggle;

        float[,] luMatrix = MatrixDecompose(m, out perm, out toggle);

        float[,] lower = ExtractLower(luMatrix);
        float[,] upper = ExtractUpper(luMatrix);

        float det = MatrixDeterminant(m);

        Console.WriteLine("Determinant of m computed via decomposition = " + det.ToString("F1"));
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private static float[,] MatrixCreate(int rows, int cols)
    {
        // allocates/creates a matrix initialized to all 0.0. assume rows and cols > 0
        // do error checking here
        float[,] result = new float[rows, cols];
        return result;
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private static float[,] MatrixDecompose(float[,] matrix, out int[] perm, out int toggle)
    {
        // Doolittle LUP decomposition with partial pivoting.
        // rerturns: result is L (with 1s on diagonal) and U; perm holds row permutations; toggle is +1 or -1 (even or odd)
        int rows = matrix.GetLength(0);
        int cols = matrix.GetLength(1);

        //Check if matrix is square
        if (rows != cols)
            throw new Exception("Attempt to MatrixDecompose a non-square mattrix");

        float[,] result = MatrixDuplicate(matrix); // make a copy of the input matrix

        perm = new int[rows]; // set up row permutation result
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) { perm[i] = i; } // i are rows counter

        toggle = 1; // toggle tracks row swaps. +1 -> even, -1 -> odd. used by MatrixDeterminant

        for (int j = 0; j < rows - 1; ++j) // each column, j is counter for coulmns
        {
            float colMax = Math.Abs(result[j, j]); // find largest value in col j
            int pRow = j;
            for (int i = j + 1; i < rows; ++i)
            {
                if (result[i, j] > colMax)
                {
                    colMax = result[i, j];
                    pRow = i;
                }
            }

            if (pRow != j) // if largest value not on pivot, swap rows
            {
                float[] rowPtr = new float[result.GetLength(1)];

                //in order to preserve value of j new variable k for counter is declared
                //rowPtr[] is a 1D array that contains all the elements on a single row of the matrix
                //there has to be a loop over the columns to transfer the values
                //from the 2D array to the 1D rowPtr array.
                //----tranfer 2D array to 1D array BEGIN

                for (int k = 0; k < result.GetLength(1); k++)
                {
                    rowPtr[k] = result[pRow, k];
                }

                for (int k = 0; k < result.GetLength(1); k++)
                {
                    result[pRow, k] = result[j, k];
                }

                for (int k = 0; k < result.GetLength(1); k++)
                {
                    result[j, k] = rowPtr[k];
                }

                //----tranfer 2D array to 1D array END

                int tmp = perm[pRow]; // and swap perm info
                perm[pRow] = perm[j];
                perm[j] = tmp;

                toggle = -toggle; // adjust the row-swap toggle
            }

            if (Math.Abs(result[j, j]) < 1.0E-20) // if diagonal after swap is zero . . .
                return null; // consider a throw

            for (int i = j + 1; i < rows; ++i)
            {
                result[i, j] /= result[j, j];
                for (int k = j + 1; k < rows; ++k)
                {
                    result[i, k] -= result[i, j] * result[j, k];
                }
            }
        } // main j column loop

        return result;
    } // MatrixDecompose

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private static float MatrixDeterminant(float[,] matrix)
    {
        int[] perm;
        int toggle;
        float[,] lum = MatrixDecompose(matrix, out perm, out toggle);
        if (lum == null)
            throw new Exception("Unable to compute MatrixDeterminant");
        float result = toggle;
        for (int i = 0; i < lum.GetLength(0); ++i)
            result *= lum[i, i];

        return result;
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private static float[,] MatrixDuplicate(float[,] matrix)
    {
        // allocates/creates a duplicate of a matrix. assumes matrix is not null.
        float[,] result = MatrixCreate(matrix.GetLength(0), matrix.GetLength(1));
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); ++i) // copy the values
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); ++j)
                result[i, j] = matrix[i, j];
        return result;
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private static float[,] ExtractLower(float[,] matrix)
    {
        // lower part of a Doolittle decomposition (1.0s on diagonal, 0.0s in upper)
        int rows = matrix.GetLength(0); int cols = matrix.GetLength(1);
        float[,] result = MatrixCreate(rows, cols);
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
            {
                if (i == j)
                    result[i, j] = 1.0f;
                else if (i > j)
                    result[i, j] = matrix[i, j];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private static float[,] ExtractUpper(float[,] matrix)
    {
        // upper part of a Doolittle decomposition (0.0s in the strictly lower part)
        int rows = matrix.GetLength(0); int cols = matrix.GetLength(1);
        float[,] result = MatrixCreate(rows, cols);
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
            {
                if (i <= j)
                    result[i, j] = matrix[i, j];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Any comments or ideas on how to improve this code (especially this part):

```
 //----tranfer 2D array to 1D array BEGIN

                for (int k = 0; k < result.GetLength(1); k++)
                {
                    rowPtr[k] = result[pRow, k];
                }

                for (int k = 0; k < result.GetLength(1); k++)
                {
                    result[pRow, k] = result[j, k];
                }

                for (int k = 0; k < result.GetLength(1); k++)
                {
                    result[j, k] = rowPtr[k];
                }

                //----tranfer 2D array to 1D array END
```

...are welcome.

Comment: This code not can detriment matrix 4*4 ={0012,0051,6790,0795}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optimizing for performance and readability you may want to avoid the 3 executions of the same loop:

```
for (int k = 0; k < result.GetLength(1); k++){
    var swapTemp = result[pRow, k];
    result[pRow, k] = result[j, k]
    result[j, k] = swapTemp;
}
```

You may also want to loop backwards (try it and see if it works out better for you):

```
for (int k = result.GetLength(1)-1; k >= 0; k--)
```

And finally, something a little non-intuitive. Use double over float for accuracy and speed in .NET as your floats are probably converted to double anyway. CLR via C# covers this quirk but again, test it out as things may have changed.

Comment: OK, I will try that. FLOAT is requested in much bigger complete program, this determinant calculation is just a part of it.

Comment: Why do you suggest looping backwards? I really doubt doing that would be more efficient.

Comment: @svick I haven't tested it all around (so give it a try and see) but some list structures will have the Count property for example re-evaluated each iteration.

Comment: @Dandy I think that would be an argument for caching that value in a local variable before the loop, not for looping backwards. That way, it's clear what are you doing and why. In any case, doing that would be a micro-optimization, which: 1. should not be done in normal code 2. should be supported by measuring the specific case.

Comment: @svick Yeah, optimizing the iteration of that loop does reduce readability but what is "normal code?" Perhaps this is a special case and it may be beneficial to try or maybe not. It is my opinion which I am sharing that sometimes micro-optimization is OK and in some situations is desirable. I feel this swap is a great place for it especially if it is applied to many small matrices. Also forgot to mention that in addition to reducing evaluations of list count it may be possible for the JIT to remove range checking by changing the iteration.

Answer (score 1):

**Unused functions**

Removing these 3 lines does not affect the final result.

```
float[,] luMatrix = MatrixDecompose(m, out perm, out toggle);

float[,] lower = ExtractLower(luMatrix);
float[,] upper = ExtractUpper(luMatrix);
```

**Comments**

I don't really see the point in `// -----------------------------` on top of your methods. You can just type `///` which automatically propose a neat documentation, per example, in the MatrixCreate function :

```
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="rows"></param>
    /// <param name="cols"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static float[,] MatrixCreate(int rows, int cols)
```

**Hardcoded values**

They are usually a bad idea (what happens if, per example, you use this value somewhere else, and decide to change it someday?):

```
 if (Math.Abs(result[j, j]) < 1.0E-20) // if diagonal after swap is zero . . .
     return null; // consider a throw
```

Another option would be to have a `threshold` or `tolerance` value in your class.

**Multiple accesses inside the same loop**

Here you have to access `result[i, j]` every time in the second loop. This harms performance and makes this second loop unclear.

```
for (int i = j + 1; i < rows; ++i)
     {
          result[i, j] /= result[j, j];
          for (int k = j + 1; k < rows; ++k)
          {
              result[i, k] -= result[i, j] * result[j, k];
          }
      }
```

Could be written:

```
for (int i = j + 1; i < rows; ++i)
     {
          result[i, j] /= result[j, j];
          double intermediateMultiplier = result[i, j];
          for (int k = j + 1; k < rows; ++k)
          {
              result[i, k] -=  intermediateMultiplier * result[j, k];
          }
      }
```

**Function naming**

`ExtractLower` and `ExtractUpper` are kind of misguiding, I would expect that `ExtractLower(x)=ExtractUpper(Transpose(x))`, but this is not the case as each function treats the diagonal in a different manner.

In order to improve readability, I would write a `Transpose` method and a `SetDiagonalValuesTo(float[,] matrix, double value)`

```
private static float[,] Transpose(float[,] matrix)
{
    int rows = matrix.GetLength(0); int cols = matrix.GetLength(1);
    float[,] result = MatrixCreate(rows, cols);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
        {
            result[i, j] = matrix[j, i];
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private static float[,] ExtractLower(float[,] matrix)
{
    return ExtractUpper(Transpose(matrix));
}

private static float[,] SetDiag(float[,] matrix, float diagonalValue)
{
    int rows = matrix.GetLength(0);
    float[,] result = MatrixCreate(rows, rows);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        result[i, i] = diagonalValue;
    }
    return result;
}
```